# Wordpress..After change url image, image still have previous permalink

Tags: wordpress, image, permalinks

i have changed url image with define( 'UPLOADS' etc). It work. I have till changed manual image url. But wordpress still have deafult path /wp-content/upload on old image. Only new image appear to be correctly. (i can't re upload all image!!) How i can do ??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The URL to your images is stored with the hostname fully qualified domain prepended. If you just need to replace the content of your old posts, you can loop through all of the posts in your database, then replace the old URL with the new one, then update the post to the database using [`wp_update_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).

```
// get all published posts
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );

// the full old URL, for replacing
$old_upload_baseurl = 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads';

// get the new upload info
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

// loop over the posts and update the content
if ( $posts->have_posts() ): while ( $posts->have_posts() ): $posts->the_post();
    // get the current (unfiltered) content. 
    // don't use get_the_content() as it will filter the response.
    $post_content = $post->post_content;

    // replace the old url with the new url
    $post_content = preg_replace( $old_upload_baseurl, $upload_dir['baseurl'], $post_content );

    // update the post content
    $post_data = array(
        'ID' => $post->ID,
        'post_content' => $post_content
    );
    wp_update_post( $post_data );
endwhile; endif;
```